Mute Button LED Not Functioning on ThinkPad E16 Gen 1 with Ubuntu 24.04
I'm using a ThinkPad E16 Gen 1 with an Intel processor and running Ubuntu 24.04. While the mute button on my keyboard correctly mutes and unmutes the system, the LED indicator for the mute button does not turn on or off as expected.
I can manually control the LED by changing the value in /sys/class/leds/platform::mute/brightness,
but I'd like to have this functionality automated.
Can anyone provide guidance on how to fix this issue so that the mute button's LED works properly?
Thanks in advance for your help!
